# ¿Cómo puedo tener a disposición de mi programa una serie de datos variables por empresa?

Tags: c#

Estoy comenzando en la programación en C# y requiero tener durante toda la ejecuación de mi aplicativo una serie de datos que son por empresas y que me identifican a ésta compañia, basicamente son: Identificación, nombre de la empresa, nombre del usuario que ingreso al sistema, y otros datos que me sirven para validaciones, impresiones y muestas dentro de algunos formularios.

¿Cómo puedo tenerlas disponibles sin necesidad de tener variables públicas?

Comment: Te recomiendo que reformules tu pregunta, ya que esta totalmente basada en opiniones, y es algo que en StackOverflow no está permitido, te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo Preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tengo dudas de si es una pregunta apropiada para el sitio, podía considerarse como basada en opiniones. Pero como norma general las variables "globales" no son una buena idea, y están desaconsejadas. Depende del caso cual puede ser la alternativa, para darte una respuesta mejor deberías poner algun ejemplo en concreto.

Comment: podrias explicar cual es la funcionalidad de estos valores? es algo relacionado con la configuracion o son datos que ingresa el usuario y necesitas mantenerlos entre forms

Comment: Al ingresar un usuario, quisiera cargar algunos datos tomados de ciertas tablas, estos datos me ayudaran durante la ejecución de todo el programa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas hacer se puede solucionar de manera bastante sencilla con el uso del [Patrón Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton).

Su aplicación es bastante sencilla, lo que vamos a hacer, es, utilizar una clase con constructor privado, y un método (en el caso de C# una propiedad) que, en caso de existir una instancia la devuelva, y caso contario la cree.

```
public class EmpresaSingleton
{
    //La instancia privada.
    private static EmpresaSingleton mInstancia;
    //Getter donde, si la instancia no existe la creo, caso contrario, devuelvo la existente..
    public static EmpresaSingleton Instancia => mInstancia ?? (mInstancia = new EmpresaSingleton());
    //Lista de ejemplo donde podrías almacenar la información..
    public IEnumerable<string> Ejemplo { get; private set; }

    //El constructor privado para que la clase no pueda ser instanciada más de una vez.
    private EmpresaSingleton()
    {
        //Acá obtenes tu información....
        Ejemplo = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Luego, simplemente, deberías acceder a la información de la siguiente manera:

```
//Obtengo la instancia de empresas..
var empresas = EmpresaSingleton.Instancia;
foreach (var empresa in empresas.Ejemplo)
{
   //Hago lo que necesito en empresas..
}

//Más adelante en la ejecución..
//empresas2 es la misma instancia que empresas, no vuelve a ejecutarse el constructor.
var empresas2 = EmpresaSingleton.Instancia;
```

De esta manera, a lo largo de toda la ejecución del programa, obtendrías la información una sola vez y la reutilizarías cuando necesites.

Aclaro que esta es una implementación muy sencilla del patrón Singleton, que puede tener graves problemas en el multi-hilo, si vas a usar este método, te recomiendo que leas [este artículo](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Singleton) donde se explican muy bien las distintas maneras de implementarlo.

---

Dejo un [artículo mas](https://albertcapdevila.net/patron-diseno-singleton-csharp/),que es muy completo y esta en español, donde también se habla de las desventajas de usar este patrón.

Comment: Excelente era lo que estaba buscando, la respuesta me sirve. De todas formas leere los enlaces que me has suministrado para las opciones que tengo.